# Unable to assign variable within a subscriber

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two bits of code, one which works and one which does not. Here's the first (working) version:

```
this.jobs = this.listingsService
                    .getListings(this.title)
                    .subscribe(
                        res => {console.log(JSON.parse(res));}    
                    );
```

this correctly logs the JSON object my service sends to the console. But this:

```
this.jobs = this.listingsService
                    .getListings(this.title)
                    .subscribe(
                        res => {this.list = JSON.parse(res);}    
                    );
```

does not work. when I try to log this.list to the console outside of the subscriber, it returns undefined. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Also, here's my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

@Injectable()

export class ListingsService{
constructor(private http: Http){}
private url = 'http://localhost:3000/'

getListings(query: string){
    return this.http.get(this.url + query).map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

and the component in its entirety:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { DepluralizePipe } from './depluralize.pipe';
import { ListingsService } from './listings.service'
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
selector: 'listings',
templateUrl: './listings.component.html',
pipes: [DepluralizePipe],
providers: [ListingsService]
})

export class ListingsComponent{
title:string;
list;
jobs;
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            private listingsService: ListingsService){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( 
          params => this.title = params['title']
    )

    this.jobs = this.listingsService
                    .getListings(this.title)
                    .subscribe(
                        res => {this.list = JSON.parse(res);}    
                     );  
    }

}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you try to `"log this.list to the console"`?

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't edit it just yet, but it should be inside the ngOnInit, but outside of this.jobs subscription

Comment: The `this.list` member won't have a value until the asynchronous operation of `getListings` has completed, so if you try to log it before it's done you'll get `undefined`. That's probably the case.

Comment: Well that makes sense. Would that also be the case about trying to render this.list in the template?

Comment: You'll need to wait for the result to come back before you can use it, regardless if it's for logging or rendering.

Comment: Got it. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably logging the result before the asynchronous call has returned. To test this, try adding the `console.log` immediately after the assignment in you subscription, like this:

```
this.jobs = this.listingsService
                .getListings(this.title)
                .subscribe(res => {
                    this.list = JSON.parse(res);
                    console.log(this.list);
                 });  
}
```